# Meteor nested publications

Tags: meteor

I have two collections `A` and `B` in Meteor. For `A` I have a publication where I filter out a range of documents in `A`. Now I want to create a publications for `B` where I publish all documents in `B` that have a field `B.length` matching `A.length`.

I have not been able to find any example where this is shown but I feel it must be a standard use case. How can this be done in Meteor?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common pattern for [reywood:publish-composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite)

import { publishComposite } from 'meteor/reywood:publish-composite';

```
publishComposite('parentChild', {
    const query = ... // your filter
    find() {
        return A.find(query, { sort: { score: -1 }, limit: 10 });
    },
    children: [
        {
            find(a) {
                return B.find({length: a.length });
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

This is a quite different pattern than `serverTransform` as on the client you end up with two collections, A and B, as opposed to a synthetic single collection A that has some fields of of B. The latter is more like a SQL JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Use [serverTransform](https://github.com/maximummeteor/server-transform)

```js
Meteor.publishTransformed('pub', function() {
  const filter = {};
  return A.find(filter)
    .serverTransform({
      'B': function(doc) {
        return B.find({
          length: doc.length
        }); //this will feed directly into miniMongo as if it was a seperate publication
      }
    })
});
```